# stream.get rejected in OK api

Tags: php, api

I use ok.ru api from php.  I need get last posts in some group: https://ok.ru/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  I try use closed method stream.get, but receive follow response:

Request url: http://api.odnoklassniki.ru/fb.do?gids=00000000000000&application_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&method=stream.get&format=json&sig=5c6b6a3eb403aae3da7c48d178e4e95f&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
Array
(
    [error_code] => 10
    [error_msg] => PERMISSION_DENIED : User must grant an access to permission 'VALUABLE_ACCESS'
    [error_data] => valuable_access
)
```

I heard that I can use  auth.anonymLogin in follow way for receive more permissive token, but I get another error:

Requesr url: http://api.odnoklassniki.ru/fb.do?application_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&method=auth.anonymLogin&format=json&sig=e97c7aecc6bfffc63c18de8b0956fc14&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
Array
(
    [error_code] => 451
    [error_msg] => NOT_SESSION_METHOD
    [error_data] => 
)
```

Have you an idea? how can I get the posts stream?
I don't have access to the group and can not grant permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should try to get permission "VALUABLE_ACCESS", you need to write an email to api-support@ok.ru (https://apiok.ru/en/ext/oauth/permissions). They give permissions to anybody (I think so)
2. Example of request URL -

   https://api.ok.ru/fb.do?

   application_key=ABCDEFG

   &fields=feed.*%2Cmedia_topic.*%2Cgroup_photo.*

   &format=json

   &gid=123456789

   &method=stream.get

   &patterns=POST

   &sig=a1b2c3d4e5

   &access_token=absdefg
3. Method "stream.get" is hidden but still works. I found this https://toster.ru/q/120467 (I'm sure you understand Russian). If somebody have more information about this method I will be glad if you share it here.